# How can I show the latest artefact version on bitbucket ReadME?

Tags: maven, bitbucket, nexus

I have a private repository hosted on bitbucket. Every time I release the latest version of the artefact to Nexus, I have to update the Read me which seems very repetitive.

Is there any way/plugin which can publish the latest version of the artefact directly to my repository's overview page (ReadME.md)?

I am using Maven 3+ for building the artefact using Jenkins which publishes all artefacts to Sonatype Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely use something akin to this to add the file, likely the attach additional resources example: http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html